# Overwrite style parameter with matplotlibrc

Tags: python, matplotlib

Consider the following simple example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.style.use(['ggplot'])

plt.title("Test")
plt.scatter(*np.random.uniform(0., 1., (2, 100)))
plt.show()
```

I'd like to overwrite some of the parameters in the `ggplot` style (or any other) using a `matplotlibrc` file. I've tried generating one like so:

```
axes.titlesize     : 5      ## fontsize of the axes title
grid.color         : red    ## grid color
```

and saved it to the same folder where the script is stored. Although the `matplotlibrc` file is correctly loaded (which I check with `matplotlib.matplotlib_fname()`), the parameters in the file are not used.

Can this be done at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather simple actually. Given a custom file called `matplotlibrc` you can just use:

```
plt.style.use(['ggplot', 'matplotlibrc'])
```

That's it. The parameters defined in the `matplotlibrc` file will overwrite those in the `ggplot` style (or any other selected style).

(Thanks to tcaswell for pointing this out)